# Get Dictinct values from swift dictionary but distinct only on one key

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries like this :

```
"subtitles": [{
                "index": 0,
                "language": "eng",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 1,
                "language": "eng",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 2,
                "language": "rus",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 3,
                "language": "chi",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 4,
                "language": "est",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 5,
                "language": "hin",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 6,
                "language": "ind",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 7,
                "language": "kor",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 8,
                "language": "lav",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 9,
                "language": "lit",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 10,
                "language": "msa",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 11,
                "language": "chi",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 12,
                "language": "pol",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 13,
                "language": "tam",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 14,
                "language": "tel",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 15,
                "language": "tha",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 16,
                "language": "ukr",
                "name": ""
            }, {
                "index": 17,
                "language": "vie",
                "name": ""
            }]
```

I want the unique of language key only. In above array the 1st two elements has language "eng", but i want only first or second to be included in filtered array.

Comment: I have a pile of gravel on my driveway that I want to be somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce your array ignoring duplicated languages:

```
let reducedSubtitles = dict["subtitles"]!.reduce([[String: Any]]()) { (result, current) in
    if result.contains(where: { $0["language"] as? String == current["language"] as? String }) {
        return result
    }

    return result + [current]
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much simpleBob. This solved my purpose.

Comment: What change I need to do if I want count of all distinct languages in above example ? Let's say, I want information like  eng=2 times... and so on for all distinct value.

Answer (score 3):

Try out this solution.Hope this help you.

```
let subtitleArray:[[String:Any]] = inputDictionary["subtitles"] as! [[String:Any]]     

    var languageArray = [String]()

    var filteredSubtitleArray = subtitleArray.filter { (dict) -> Bool in

            guard let lang = dict["language"] as? String,languageArray.contains(lang) == false else {
                return false
            }

            languageArray.append(lang)

            return true
        }
```

Comment: Thank u so much for the reply. I will try this.